# How can I collect the "ids" of directed links using the NetLogo Behavior Space?

Tags: netlogo, data-collection, behaviorspace

We have stored a lot of data as attributes of links in our NetLogo model. When I use the Behavior Space to design experiments and to direct data collection, I specify the "[attribute] of link" to be extracted. However, in the CSV file I cannot see the id of the link, which is an essential to understand the data. How can I collect the ids of links in my results? From what I understand there is no primitive to enable this command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you want to extract information from individual agents (including links) using BehaviorSpace, a nice way to do it is to use the `csv` extension as explained in this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/52406247/487946

The general idea is that we can embed csv into our csv, and then use a `read_csv`-like function in R (or Python or Julia or whatever) to extract the "inner csv" from our BehaviorSpace results.

In the case of links, it would be useful to include the `who` number of each end of the link to uniquely identify it. (This is one of the very few cases where I'll advocate using a `who` number for anything.)

Let's take this silly example model:

```
extensions [ csv ]
links-own [ attribute ]

to setup
  clear-all
  create-turtles 3 [
    create-links-with other turtles [
      set attribute random-float 1
    ]
  ]
  reset-ticks
end

to go
  ask links [ set attribute attribute * 0.5 ]
  tick
end
```

It just creates three turtles with links between them, sets the `attribute` of the link to a random number and repeatedly halves that number as the model ticks.

To generate the csv that we will embed into our BehaviorSpace results, we write the following reporter:

```
to-report link-attributes-csv
  report csv:to-string
    fput ["who1" "who2" "attribute" ] 
    [ (list [ who ] of end1 [ who ] of end2 attribute) ] of links
end
```

If you try it out in the command center after running `setup`, it will output something like this:

```
observer> setup
observer> print link-attributes-csv
who1,who2,attribute
0,1,0.9409784968740699
1,2,0.9079884204004846
0,2,0.9070292656950991
```

As you can see, we have a neat little csv table, where each row represents a particular link, identified by the `who` number of the turtles it connects.

Since this reporter reports a string (and it's ok for this string to contain line breaks), we can use it directly in a BehaviorSpace experiment:

[image: example experiment]

Running this experiment (with "table output") gives the following output file:

```
"BehaviorSpace results (NetLogo 6.1.1)"
"link-attributes-example.nlogo"
"experiment"
"10/16/2019 11:00:12:495 +0100"
"min-pxcor","max-pxcor","min-pycor","max-pycor"
"-16","16","-16","16"
"[run number]","[step]","link-attributes"
"1","0","who1,who2,attribute
1,2,0.15670083797389645
0,2,0.40055350697928993
0,1,0.34892645306446335"
"2","0","who1,who2,attribute
0,1,0.2831244347856665
1,2,0.27721328746715357
0,2,0.5221352362751627"
"2","1","who1,who2,attribute
0,1,0.14156221739283326
0,2,0.26106761813758134
1,2,0.13860664373357678"
"1","1","who1,who2,attribute
0,2,0.20027675348964497
1,2,0.07835041898694822
0,1,0.17446322653223167"
"1","2","who1,who2,attribute
1,2,0.03917520949347411
0,2,0.10013837674482248
0,1,0.08723161326611584"
"2","2","who1,who2,attribute
1,2,0.06930332186678839
0,1,0.07078110869641663
0,2,0.13053380906879067"
```

It looks at bit weird with all the line breaks, but your data analysis tools should be able to deal with that. Here is how to handle this using R and the Tidyverse:

```
library(tidyverse)
df <-
  read_csv("experiment-table.csv", skip = 6) %>%
  mutate(`link-attributes` = map(`link-attributes`, read_csv)) %>%
  unnest()
```

The [`purrr::map`](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/map.html) and [`tidyr::unnest`](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/unnest.html) functions are the key ones. I won't explain them here, but its worth looking them up and familiarizing yourself with them.

Our final result looks like this:

```
# A tibble: 18 x 5
   `[run number]` `[step]`  who1  who2 attribute
            <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>
 1              1        0     1     2    0.157 
 2              1        0     0     2    0.401 
 3              1        0     0     1    0.349 
 4              2        0     0     1    0.283 
 5              2        0     1     2    0.277 
 6              2        0     0     2    0.522 
 7              2        1     0     1    0.142 
 8              2        1     0     2    0.261 
 9              2        1     1     2    0.139 
10              1        1     0     2    0.200 
11              1        1     1     2    0.0784
12              1        1     0     1    0.174 
13              1        2     1     2    0.0392
14              1        2     0     2    0.100 
15              1        2     0     1    0.0872
16              2        2     1     2    0.0693
17              2        2     0     1    0.0708
18              2        2     0     2    0.131
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Like patches, links are identified by two numbers, which are the who numbers of the two ends.  You can either save the string representation of the link (e.g., (link 0 1)) or extract the numbers as a list (or separately).  E.g.,

```
to test
  ca
  crt 2
  ask turtle 0 [create-link-with turtle 1]
  print link 0 1
  ask link 0 1 [let id sort [who] of both-ends print id] ; a list
  ask link 0 1 [let id sort [who] of both-ends
    print (word item 0 id "-" item 1 id)
  ] ; a string
end
```